# What to do if asked to write a letter of recommendation for a weak candidate?

Tags: recommendation-letter

How should a professor proceed when a student or colleague asks for a letter of recommendation and the professor does not have a high opinion of that person?

Comment: In short: Just say no.

Comment: At the risk of putting anyone on the defensive (I don't mean to); when would the answer ever not be "say no"? The letter writer would be doing the student/colleague a huge disservice by writing a weak letter but letting their expectation remain that they have a strong recommendation.

Comment: @JohnMoeller I asked because [this answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/2716/81) suggested that some people think differently.

Comment: Fair enough. I suppose that you could say, "I'll write you a recommendation, but it will have to be somewhat weak."

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Although it may be quite awkward, it is certainly acceptable to tell the student/colleague that you do not feel you can write a strong LoR for them, and to suggest that they ask someone else. This may seem rude or even unkind, but it's much better for the student/colleague in the long run than a lukewarm or poor letter.

Comment: In fact, in some cases students don't understand that they should get the _best_ letters possible, or that it's not all perfunctory.